# How can I get back Synaptics extensions in Windows 10 Anniversary update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607, synaptics-touchpad

I have a Clevo laptop that shipped with Windows 8.  I had to hunt down a specific version of the Synaptics driver to get 2-finger scrolling working properly after updating to Windows 10.  Now, Windows Anniversary Update has quietly uninstalled this driver (!!!) and 2-finger scrolling is busted again.

I don't know what the version was, and haven't had much luck finding it again.  Synaptics seems to be geared towards OEMs rather than end-users on their site, nothing there jumps out at me as helpful.  Clevo of course hasn't updated any drivers for this machine in years, so I think I'm on my own.

Comment: So your looking for somebody who knows what version it was?

Comment: Useful answers might include: "I have a similar-vintage Clevo and X drivers work", or "when Windows Anniversary uninstalls something during the upgrade, you can click on X to get it back", or "This is a common issue with Symantec drivers, instead you should change this setting / registry key to enable 2-finger scrolling", etc.

Comment: You are limiting yourself to an extremely small subset of Superusers if thats the type of answer you want.  In my experience the Synaptics drivers themselfs work flawlessly on Windows 10 Version 1607

Comment: You're right, I recognize it was a long shot -- I was hoping the issue I was encountering might have been widespread, but I probably just have a really rare and poorly supported variant of this hardware.  I could add more details, but something this esoteric might require me to dig into some specialized forums somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have looked harder on Synaptics' site.  They do in fact now list consumer-facing drivers [on their site](http://www.synaptics.com/resources).  Of course, just downloading and installing them isn't always enough -- I had to install, uninstall, manually clean up, re-install, then manually select them in Device Manager, but at the end of the day it did work.

TL;DR: I thought Windows 10 Anniversary broke Synaptics drivers for old touchpads, when in fact I just needed to download and install the latest ones.  Sorry.

Comment: The update broke it in the same way upgrading to any version of Windows would have broken it.  In the case of these major updates for Windows 10, Windows is installed, then your stuff is migrated to the new installation of Windows.  This means that applications and drivers that have in compatability testing been flagged as a problem  can be removed, which results in the user having to install the driver and/or application again.  Microsoft flags applications and device drivers, even if they are soft failures, meaning that sometimes there is no specific reason its incompatible.

Comment: That seems like the sort of thing that should at least be logged somewhere -- maybe I could figure out a list of "non-migrated" stuff by poking around in Event Viewer?